Is there a way to get around SonarQube's 100 character limit for project version names?
I am trying to run analysis on some code and everything works great except for when the project version is greater than 100 characters. My team uses the title of the branch which is typically based off an issue in our board so the names can get long. The error code is below.
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.8.0.2131:sonar (default-cli) on project {project name}: "insert long project version" is not a valid project version. The maximum length is 100 characters.

I know we could truncate it or come up with a different naming convention, but we would prefer to just change a parameter or something to allow more characters. Does anything like that exist? A quick search did not come up with much and I could not see anything obvious in the properties file. I know this may be a dead end question but thought I would ask in case there is some hidden field I can change.
I am not very familiar with sonar so an easy solution would be great but I have a feeling I will need to get into the weeds to get around this limit.

To be honest: I doubt that, because that's define in SonarQube... in their database... why do you use brnach es for project names? Usually that are the artifactid of your project... and why project version with such combination? A version is something like semver.org etc. ? Maybe juse an issue number to get relationship to your issue tracking system...
